# Properties from 'asyncData()' aren't available in 'mounted()' upon first page loading

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, static-site

We have a statically generated website that is run by Nuxt 2.14.
In some page components I need several properties from the `asyncData()` function in order for the app to work correctly.
In development mode, when I reload the page, `asyncData()` works totally correct: it gets triggered, and corresponding properties are merged into the component instance.

However, when I do the same action on the same page in production version, it fails: during the execution of the `mounted()` hook needed properties from the `asyncData()` are missing.
I guess this is caused by the fact that this hook is triggered server-side when loading the page for the first time.

But why then it cannot be reproduced locally, even after execution of the `nuxt generate` command?

Comment: When running locally, you're using a server so your app is behaving more like an SSR Nuxt one. If you try `generate` and then `start`, can you reproduce the issue locally (just to be sure that you were not using `dev`)? `mounted()` is a hook available only on the [client side](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle/#client) of things. I know that `asyncData()` can be a bit annoying because it is supposed to be triggered only on client-side navigation and not upon a hard refresh of the page. Is it what is happening? Do you need a blocking navigation or is the `fetch()` hook also fine?

Comment: @kissu yes, I was trying to reproduce it via generate command locally. However, I noticed that ‘asyncData’ ‘s properties were missing in ‘mounted’ even in properly functioning components. So I guess this should be normal behaviour on production. I can’t test it locally rn, but I believe that in development version they’re presented. This is just a weird feature of static generation. I guess, we shouldn’t try access ‘asyncData’ in ‘mounted’ when developing static websites.

Comment: `mounted` is available after `asyncData` but [only on client-side](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle#client), it is not available on the server.

Answer (score -1):

That should work perfectly

```html
<template>
  <div>{{ data }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async asyncData({ $axios }) {
    const { data } = await $axios.get(
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'
    )
    return { data }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.data)
  },
}
</script>
```

Regarding the lifecycle of Nuxt2: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle/

---

Public GitHub repo of a working solution: https://github.com/kissu/yes-it-works